# Matplotlib pause, hold last iteration

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an animation loop in matplotlib, and I would like to freeze the last iteration of the animation. I am using the `pause` function with a conditional to check for the last iteration. However, in the last iteration, the previous frame is shown -- not the last frame.

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
x = np.linspace(0, 6.28, 401)

freqs = np.arange(5)

for f in freqs:
    print f

    ax.plot(x, np.sin(f*x))   
    ax.set_title('$\sin(%d x)$'%f)

    if f < freqs[-1]:
        plt.pause(1)
        ax.cla()
    else:
        print "hi"
        plt.show() # Fails: shows frame with `f==3`.
```

This prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4
hi
```

However, the last frame (with `f==4`) is never shown. The animation freezes with title, "sin(3x)", and corresponding plot data for `f==3`, not 4.

Is there a "proper" way to hold the last frame? For example, `plt.pause(10000)` would work, but seems like a hack.

Comment: The result of `print (freqs[-1])` is 4. Therefore when you say `if f < freqs[-1]:`, f=4 wont be executed. You just need to add less than or equal to like `if f <= freqs[-1]:`

Comment: The point of checking `f < freqs[-1]` is because the behavior on last iteration should be different. I do not want to pause on the last iteration, but rather hold it. If I change to `<=`, then the `pause` block will run on all the iterations, which is not what I want... unless I'm misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: Yeah you're right... So, on my system if I add `plt.pause(0.01)` on the `else:` statement just before `plt.show()` then it holds the f==4 frame.

Comment: I noticed that as well. It's not very intuitive that it has to work this way, but oh well! Add your comment as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always find it much more intuitive to set up the plot first, draw it and then start the animation.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
x = np.linspace(0, 6.28, 401)
freqs = np.arange(5)
line, = ax.plot([],[])
ax.set_xlim([x[0], x[-1]])   
ax.set_ylim([-1, 1])   
ax.set_title('$\sin(x)$')
fig.canvas.draw() 

for f in freqs:
    print f

    line.set_data(x, np.sin(f*x))   
    ax.set_title('$\sin(%d x)$'%f)
    fig.canvas.draw()

    if f < freqs[-1]:
        plt.pause(1)
    else:
        print "hi"
plt.show()
```

Comment: Nice. I assume that this is more efficient than clearing the axis on each iteration as well.